# Data Entry Form Libraries available for Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

Does anyone know of any libraries for Objective-C Cocoa Touch that provide data entry fields for all different types of inputs (e.g. Date fields, Boolean, Numbers, Integers, etc). Aside from just the built in text fields that accept all inputs? I know you can limit input in the text field delegate and change the keyboard, but stuff like Date and boolean (yes/no) aren't as slick with that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the [UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/index.html) framework has some pretty nice controls for entering [dates](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html), [booleans](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [numbers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), etc.

Comment: Is this the same UIKit that is provided within the Interface Builder? From what I could tell stuff like the UIDatePicker still needed you to tie it to a label and it became difficult to control fluid tabbing between textfields and datepicker fields when using the Next button on the keyboard. Is this a different set of tools than the ones in Interface Builder?

Comment: @Adam - Yes, this is the Apple UIKit framework (as clicking on the link shows). there is no such thing as tabbing between fields.  Any app that shows a "next" button for field advancement is implementing that manually.  Feel free to do the same.

Comment: Aw man. I've already looked at that then. I worked with the DatePicker and it had issues when getting the Next button to tab between fields of different data types. I was kinda hoping there would be a library somebody built for a generic data entry form with different data types.